# event handling thread in a GUI application C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-interface

I am working on a GUI application which internally connects to a server. A user can use the GUI application to send requests and get data from the server once connected.

To start with, we've gone with a single threaded design, where on a button click, the app parses the event received and accordingly sends a request to the server to get the required data.

At this point, we are still doing prototype work, but was thinking of the following change in the way this works -

1. Have an event handler thread which receives events when a user clicks on something.
2. This thread will process the events and call the appropriate functions and send a request to the server. (all this will happen in the context of the event handler thread)
3. How do I handle events that are received when the app is still waiting for data from the server? I was thinking of having the event handler thread either rejecting the previous ongoing request and serving the new event received. 
   From a user perspective, when a user clicks on a new button when the previous button is still waiting for a response, we should just dump what we were doing earlier and handle the new button click.

Please comment on this. This is the first time I am working on a client gui app and request your inputs on this one.

Comment: You can simply send request in another thread.

Comment: Is it appropriate for your application to just ignore the result from the first call to the server, i.e like a web browser, there are no side effects from ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few strategies. if it's appropriate for your application to ignore the results, you could just cancel the connection and run a new one. Some server applications do not like this though.

If it is inappropriate for your application to just drop connection, for instance a database call that is updating records, you could run requests out of a queue, you put a request in a queue and your thread pulls it out and does the work, and then notifies your application it is done with one.

Another approach is to run each request in its own thread, this would allow you to just ignore the results from the ones you dont want, or allow you to actually do more than one task at a time.